# Loop through entries in a Matrix block type

Tags: matrix

I have a Matrix field with 4 Block types. I loop through them like this

```
{% for block in entry.MatrixFieldHandle %}
    {% set type = block.type.handle %}

    {% switch type %}
        {% case 'BlockType1' %}
            {{ block.fieldHandle }}

        {% case 'BlockType2' %}
            {{ block.fieldHandle }}
```

within one of these cases, I need to loop through the entries:

```
{% case 'BlockType3' %}
    {% for row in block|batch(2) %}
        <div class="row">

        {% for block in row %}
            <div class="col">{{ block.fieldHandle }}</div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

The html output is close, but I do not get any content displayed. What is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you are talking about your block type having a Entries field within.

You simply loop through it like this:

```
{% case 'BlockType3' %}
<div class="row">
{% for entry in block.entriesFieldHandle %}
    <div class="col">{{ entry.title }}</div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```